# How to position header of the page and sidebar navigation?

Tags: html, css

I got a problem with correct positioning two containers.

There is a painted image how it supposes to look like.

[image: click here to see]

I want to scroll only the articles, header title and sidebar `nav` should be sticky to the page.

The problem is I have no idea how to correctly write code to make it looks like that in the picture (I mean these two headers and sidebar). Here's my code I already made.

```css
.page-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 57px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#011A25, #022C3F 40%);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 15px grey;
  display: inline-block;
}

.page-header h1 {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px black;
}

.site-nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  /*stay in place*/
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #011018;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 17px #011018;
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.single-article {
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #292929;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px grey;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="site-nav">
    <header class="nav-header">
      <h2>Spis treści</h2>
    </header>
    <section class="nav-menu">
      <a href="#"><span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span>Interfejsy</a>
      <hr>
      <a href="#">Procesory<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      <hr>
      <a href="#">Przechowywanie danych<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      <hr>
      <a href="#">Grafika<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      <hr>
      <a href="#">Linux<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      <hr>
      <a href="#">Sieci komputerowe<span class="fa fa-angle-double-down fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
    </section>
  </nav>
  <header class="page-header">
    <h1>
      Podstawy technik programowania
    </h1>
  </header>
  <main class="main-content">
    <article class="single-article">
      <header class="article-title">
        <h1>Wstęp</h1>
      </header>
      <span class="split-line"></span>
      <div class="article-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    </article>
  </main>

</body>
```

Comment: I guess `.main-content` width should be : `width: calc(100% - **asideWidth**)`. It should also be offseted by header height with something like padding : `padding: **headerHeight**` .And aside and header in fixed position

Comment: Check i posted relevant example for the same

Comment: Thanks guys :) Both of your answers helped me to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a working example relevant of the same issue, I  created it with using of `flex` properties of css

*Hope it will help you..*

**[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lokeshg27/tfeunrxp/1/)**

> Note - There is a paint-image how it suppose to look-like.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.right-side {
  width: 30%;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit illo omnis aperiam mollitia non fugiat, at in ratione harum ullam alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit illo omnis aperiam mollitia non fugiat, at in ratione harum ullam alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit
      illo omnis aperiam mollitia non fugiat, at in ratione harum ullam alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi magnam iusto fugit illo omnis aperiam mollitia non fugiat,
      at in ratione harum ullam alias dicta, excepturi quod sed delectus veniam?<br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    Right side
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, it is almost exactly what I wanted to get. But is there a way to make the 'right side' have the same width regardless of the size/width of page? :)

Comment: Yes, I gave 30% width to the right-side so it will take 30% width of any viewport.

Comment: Yea I got it :) but I want sidebar to doesn't change its width. For example, if the page has 1200px width, the sidebar has 300px width. When the page has 600px width, sidebar still has 300px width.

Comment: Then use width in pixel

Comment: Wrap all html into the div and assign css for wrap div use width in px like 960px and margin auto to center. Or assign justify-content center to main div to center and use px width to box and right-side